# Handing error with nested promises in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, es6-promise

Need to catch all the error in the last outer catch block when an error occurs in the nested promise block.

```
let docs = {
  total: 0,
  total_downloaded: 0,
  plan_type: null,
};

Document.findAll({
  where: {
    report_request_id: req.params.requestId
  },
  attributes: ["id", "folder_name", "total_file"],
})
  .then(documents => {
    documents.forEach(document => {
        docs.total += 1;

        if (document.get("status") == 1) {
          docs.total_downloaded += 1;
        }
    });
  })
  .then(function() {
    Request.findOne({
      where: {
        id: req.params.requestId
      }
    })
      .then(request => {
        //Suppose I got error here
        docs.plan_type = request.plan_type;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Block A
        throw err;
      });
  })
  .then(function() {
    res.status(200).send(docs);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Block B
    res.status(400).send(err);
  });
```

As of now, I get success(200) every time even if I get an error in catch block A

Comment: I think you should use promises in this case rather than using nested structure to catch the error one by one.

Comment: You should use async await,this link will help you https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-async-await-in-node-js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the statement `return` to chain the promise of `Request.findOne()` .

```
let docs = {
  total: 0,
  total_downloaded: 0,
  plan_type: null,
};

Document.findAll({
  where: {
    report_request_id: req.params.requestId
  },
  attributes: ["id", "folder_name", "total_file"],
})
  .then(documents => {
    documents.forEach(document => {
        docs.total += 1;

        if (document.get("status") == 1) {
          docs.total_downloaded += 1;
        }
    });
  })
  .then(function() {
    return Request.findOne({
      where: {
        id: req.params.requestId
      }
    })
      .then(request => {
        //Suppose I got error here
        docs.plan_type = request.plan_type;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // Block A
        throw err;
      });
  })
  .then(function() {
    res.status(200).send(docs);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Block B
    res.status(400).send(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use Promises or async/await to catch the error in one catch block. You can throw errors specifically in each await function which in turn uses promise.
 Something like.

```
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        // do something
        resolve(output);
    } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
    }
});

const b = //... similar to a();
const c = //... similar to a();

const main = async () => {
    try {
        const f = await a();
        const i = await b(f); // if data from a is to be passed to b
        const y = await c(i); // if data from a is to be passed to b
        return y;
    } catch(error){
        // catch all errors
        throw new Error( error );
    }
}

main().then(( data )=>{
    // on success do something with data

}).catch((error)=>{
    //catch all errors and do something

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, @uday8486 for the answer but I was looking for the solution in the existing source code